# How do delete a row in a table from Notion?

Tags: notion-api

I'm using Notion Tables (one type of their databases). I'm trying to wrap my mental model around how they interact with data - is a row in a table a "block" or a page or something else?

Here's all the info from the documentation: https://developers.notion.com/reference/delete-a-block

At the end of the day, I'm just trying to delete a row like I would in any other database, via the API.

Answer (score 0):

Answer, the terms 'block' and 'page' are often interchangeable with Notion. Further, every row in a table/database is a 'page' (or 'block').

As a result, the above code basically works like the following:

```js
await notion.blocks.delete(block_id: 'PUT THE ID OF THE ROW OF THE DATABASE HERE');
```

It returns the full object, but has been deleted from the DB.